# Trouble installing NPM packages?

Tags: npm

I have a box running 14.04 - I've uploaded the source files for a site and when I run `npm install` at site root, I see the progress bar run through but on completion, the `node_modules` is empty?

However, if I install each listed package individually; e.g. `npm install gulp`, they install just fine?

Anyone encountered this before? It has me baffled..

Answer (score 1):

Turns out `npm i` was silently dying due to my box running out of memory before completing due to multiple streams.

Adding a swap resolved it: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-12-04